# Проверка слов строки на наличие буквы, на которую кончается и начинается

Tags: c++

Дана строка, состоящая из символов латинского алфавита, разделенных
пробелами (одним или несколькими). Определить количество слов, которые начинаются и заканчиваются одной и той же буквой.
Не знаю, как исправить траблы :(

```cpp
#include <iostream> 
#include <clocale> 
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    string ss, b;
    int k = 0;
    cout << "Введите букву, которая на которую должно начинаться и заканчиваться слово: ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Ввeдите текст латиницей (ctrl^Z - в отдельной строке строке для завершения):" << endl;
    while (cin >> ss)
    {
        char s = ss[0];
        if (s == b || s == b)
            k++;
    }
    cout << "Количество слов,начинающихся на букву К:" << k << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: вы сравниваете символ со строкой s == b _ это первая ошибка...И вообше не имеет смысла для одного символа держать строку. И вы не заданное выполнять пытаетесь, а совершенно другое.  if (s == b || s == b)... что вы пытались этим сказать?

Comment: Сравнение для того, что бы проверить, имеется ли в слове буква

Comment: плохо, что вы все еще не заметили, что это совсем не то "пальто "

Comment: у вас нет условия выхода из цикла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажется в вашем задании не говорится о сравнении с каким то символом, а нужно просто смотреть, чтобы первый и последный были одинаковы, поэтому (один из вариантов решения):

```
string s, temp;     
getline(cin, s); //ввод всей строки 
istringstream ss(s);
size_t k = 0;
while (ss >> temp)
    if (temp.front() ==  temp.back())
        ++k;
cout << endl << k;
```

Comment: Первый символ это получается s[0] а последний какой ?

Comment: Последний зависит от размера строки, это будет `s[s.size() - 1]`